# Swipe gesture action is not called

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, tvos, uiswipegesturerecognizer

I am trying to do basic 2D snake game for tv.

I have problem with gestures. I add gestures to view in `didMoveToView(view: SKView)` method inside GameScene class. This class also extends SKScene class. This is my `didMoveToView` method and `handleSwipe` method.

```
override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
    let swipeUp = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "handleSwipe:")
    swipeUp.direction = .Up
    view.addGestureRecognizer(swipeUp)

    let swipeDown = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "handleSwipe:")
    swipeDown.direction = .Down
    view.addGestureRecognizer(swipeDown)

    let swipeLeft = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "handleSwipe:")
    swipeLeft.direction = .Left
    view.addGestureRecognizer(swipeLeft)

    let swipeRight = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "handleSwipe:")
    swipeRight.direction = .Right
    view.addGestureRecognizer(swipeRight)

    backgroundColor = SKColor.blackColor()
}

func handleSwipe(sender: UIGestureRecognizer) {
    if let gesture = sender as? UISwipeGestureRecognizer {
        switch(gesture.direction) {
            case UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.Right: m_snake.moveRight()
            case UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.Left: m_snake.moveLeft()
            case UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.Up: m_snake.moveUp()
            case UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.Down: m_snake.moveDown()
            default:
                break
        }
    }
}
```

It seems like my program does not enter `handleSwipe` method when I swipe on remote. I am testing this on simulator. Any idea why this doesn't work?

Comment: Are you swiping on the Simulator's Apple TV Remote? Did you hold down the Option key while swiping? When I implemented your code, the handleSwipe method was called but very intermittently.

Comment: Yes, I am running on Simulator's Apple TV Remote. I've aldo hold down the Option key while swiping. How do you know that handleSwipe method was called? I've put breakpoint inside this method and nothing is working :/

Comment: You need to put the breakpoint on the first "if" to verify that it correctly entered the method.

Comment: check if the user interaction is enabled

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
func handleSwipes(sender:UISwipeGestureRecognizer) {
    if let gesture = sender as? UISwipeGestureRecognizer {
        switch(gesture.direction) {
            case UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.Right: m_snake.moveRight()
            case UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.Left: m_snake.moveLeft()
            case UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.Up: m_snake.moveUp()
            case UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.Down: m_snake.moveDown()
            default:
                break
        }
    }
}
```

I just tested your code in my current project and it worked perfectly fine

To get the swipe working, configure the simulator like this;

- Show the remote by going to Hardware > Show Apple TV Remote
- Hold down option while your mouse is over the trackpad.
- Move the mouse sideways in a swipe movement

Comment: this does not work. And I don't see how that one letter should help

Comment: I added some informations on the config. I am not sure why the method is not called for you. Have you tried simply printing a message on the console to be sure, like "print("I swiped")" before the "if"? I will test a little bit more today.

Comment: First, to answer you previous comment: Yes, I put the breakpoint on the first if statement ;) Second: I don't know why exactly is working, but now it really does work. Thank you :)